# Web Api 2 determine controller return type based on accept header

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I create a web api 2 controller that can be called from the client to whether download the file stored in server local disk or just get an url too that file. I want to implement this functionality into one controller action and determine the result by `content-negotiation`.

If client request with `application/json` it will return the json value with `url` property in it. If client request `image/*` it will the image itself.

Could it be possible to do it in one controller action??

Comment: Why you would like to use one action to different tasks? Why don't you use parameter which help you to determine what the result should be?

Comment: Initially, I thought to leverage content-negotiation so it'll comply to RESTFul design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?

```
public IHttpActionResult SomeAction()
{
    switch(Request.Headers.Accept.ToString())
    {
        case "application/json":
            // Return the whole DTO with the image URI
            break;

        case "image/jpeg":
            // Build a response containing a StreamContent 
            // or ByteArrayContent
            break;
    }
}
```